# How to administer an APC Smart UPS 6000?

Tags: ups, apc-smart-ups

I did a scan on a APC Smart UPS 6000 that is connected to the network, and it was discovered with a particular mac address and 62078 and 999 closed ports.

I tried using telnet to login to the server and also ssh on that port; is there some sort of proprietary software I need to remote into it?

Comment: Here's the manufacturer's software page for that model, take a look; http://www.apc.com/products/resource/include/techspec_index.cfm?base_sku=SURT6000XLT-CC&xtmc=6000&xtcr=4&tab=software

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would use the Network Management Card and the CD that came with it.

This documentation should give you what you are after: [UPS Network Management Cards](http://www.apc.com/products/resource/include/techspec_index.cfm?base_sku=AP9630&tab=documentation)

Specifically the Install Guide here: http://www.apcmedia.com/salestools/PMAR-96DHBM/PMAR-96DHBM_R1_EN.pdf

And the User Guide here: http://www.apcmedia.com/salestools/PMAR-969FZW/PMAR-969FZW_R0_EN.pdf

There is a device IP wizard tool here: http://www.apc.com/products/resource/include/techspec_index.cfm?base_sku=AP9630&tab=software but you'll need an APC account (you can register for one based on the serial # of the UPS) to download the software.

Answer (score 0):

I know that we control access to our APC UPSes via a vApp.  The [virtual appliance software download is here](http://www.apc.com/resource/include/techspec_index.cfm?base_sku=Surt6000xli&tab=software), and you guys might have that set up for the UPS already.  In our configuration, access to the UPS is blocked from anywhere but the vApp we set up.  Might be the same case for you as well.

[If not, see TheCleaner's answer for a better solution](https://serverfault.com/a/568797/118258) than we used when we set these up.  From the looks of his answer, it doesn't require physically connecting a laptop to the UPS with a serial cable, which is what I ended up doing.